# File Upload with apollo-upload-client payload formatting

Tags: file-upload, graphql, multipartform-data

I am using apollo-upload-client for file upload. The payload it creates is:

```html
{
query: mutation($file: Upload!) { singleUpload(file: $file) { id } },
variables: {
file: File // a.txt
}
}

and the payload is:
...
{ "0": ["variables.file"] }
--------------------------cec8e8123c05ba25
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Is there a way for the payload name="0" property to equal the one stated in the mutation for example

```html
{
query: mutation($file: Upload!) { singleUpload(file: $file) { id } },
variables: {
someCustomName: File // a.txt
}
}

and the payload to be :
...
{ "0": ["variables.someCustomName"] }
--------------------------cec8e8123c05ba25
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="someCustomName"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Is there a way to modify this name="0" property? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mapping entry points to used file variable name (`$file`)

... you can rename it like:

```
mutation($someFile: Upload!) {
  singleUpload(file: $someFile) {
    id
```

... and of course `variables: {someFile: File}`